# Unknown Audio Driver Error

Tags: ios, security, audio, ios5

I'm getting strange error message in Console, but application functions properly. Has anyone else seen this error. What does it mean?

> 2011-11-21 09:52:39.306 MyApplicationName[9871:1f07] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Developer42/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

(Repeat 8)

Comment: Have you linked to the security.framework?  If so, it seems this is has been a problem in the Security.framework for a while now.  Submit a bug report to apple.

Comment: it seems to be a common problem since the release of iOS5 SDK. In my opinion it could be a problem with the file permissions

Comment: security.framework and corefoundation.framework were not included, but adding those didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems only to be an issue in the simulator from my experiences, but and run on a device and you will see it won't appear.

It's as others have said its a security issue, but seems to be isolated to when the simulator tries to access files on the Mac. As it stands there doesn't seem to be anything to worry about, or that apple has said anyway.

So for the time being ignore the errors, but keep them in mind for the future

Comment: You're right. The message/warning/error doesn't appear on the device, so i'm ignoring this for now - as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error.
The cause reason seems to be I copy the project full folder(ex:audioGame), then I paste to another path. then running the simulator and run the 2 project at the same time...

it will cause the error happened ...

example :

```
/project/07022012/audioGame/xxx.proj
/project/07062012/audioGame/xxx.proj
```

i.e. : Running the same project at different folder cause simulator confuse ... then it will crazy ...

I think if you clean simulator's backup data, and re-build the project, the error will disappear, it should be the question of the simulator load library.